# Is it possible to pass the elements of a list as arguments of one function call in C#?

Tags: c#, list, function, dll, parameter-passing

I am writing a bot designed to interact with an online game. I am using a function called "Send" which is defined like so:

```
public void Send(string type, params object[] parameters);
```

"Send" is a function which can have a variable number of arguments, thanks to the `params` keyword. If I am storing these arguments in a `List<object>`, can I pass this list of arguments to the function without having to write different code for each possible number of arguments?

I know that if that `params` keyword wasn't there I could just pass the whole list as one argument using `List<T>.ToArray()`, but the Send function is defined in a preprepared library which I can't alter.

Comment: Try and you'll find out!

Comment: Try passing `myList.ToArray()`. You can pass arrays to `params` paramteter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small explanation:

```
var myList = new List<object>() { 1, "foo", "bar"};

Send(type, myList.ToArray());         //this will invoke: void Send(string, object, object, object);
Send(type, (object)myList.ToArray()); //this will invoke: void Send(string, object);
Send(type, myList);                   //this will invoke: void Send(string, object);
```

So if you want your list to be considered as **params** - you can invoke ToArray(), if you want it to be considered as **single parameter** - just cast it to object.

Answer (score 0):

> but the Send function is defined in a preprepared library which I can't alter.

You could define an extension method,

```
// Where Lib is the type that contains the Send method.
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void Send(this Lib lib, string type, int obj)
    {
        lib.Send(type, obj);
    }

    public static void Send(this Lib lib, string type, List<object> objs)
    {
        lib.Send(type, objs.ToArray());
    }

    // Other overloads
}
```

Then you use it just like it was built into the library to being with,

```
var lib = new Lib();
lib.Send(type, 1) // Call Send(this Lib lib, string type, int obj)
```